# search a value from sqlite always return empty result

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Hi I'm trying to add the preferred option to my application I started with sqlite to save the URL of the image but I have a problem when adding image url to favorite by this code :

```
public void AddtoFavorite(Post pj) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE_CATNAME, pj.getName());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE_URL, pj.getImgUrl());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

It is added successfully but when i want to check if image url exist in database or not

```
  public List<Post> getFavRow(String url) {
        List<Post> dataList = new ArrayList();
        @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Favorite WHERE imageurl = '" + url + "'", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Post contact = new Post();
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                contact.setImgUrl(cursor.getString(1));
                dataList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

always i get empty list as result.

Comment: I suggest that you use `adb` to connect to your device or emulator and run the raw query in the `sqlite3` command-line tool. This will show you what data is in your database.

Comment: the string `url` and `pj.getImgUrl()` are same? maybe you can use `like` instead of `=` operator

Answer (score 0):

You should use getReadableDatabase() instead of getWritableDatabase() in your getFavRow() function

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: Please ensure you actually have data in your table.

Comment: yeah when i go to favorite activity i get data

Comment: @ali how are you getting the data in favorite activity? as you mentioned you are getting empty result

Answer (score 0):

Try

WHERE imageurl LIKE '%" + url + "%'"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public List<Post> getFavRow(String url) {
List<Post> dataList = new ArrayList();    

 String[] selectQuery = {"YOUR", "TABLE", "COLUMNS"};
 String selection = "IMAGEURL = ?";
 String[] selectionArgs = {url};
 Cursor cursor = database.query(yourTable, selectQuery, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
 while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    Post contact = new Post();
    contact.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME")));
    contact.setImgUrl(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("IMAGEURL")));
    dataList.add(contact);
  }
 cursor.close();
 return dataList;
}
```